# how to define a location in a dataframe by using values of a dataframe row?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use the value of df.d to define the location, that df.a refers to when applying the calculation. But this apparently does not work.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

randn = np.random.randn
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0], 'b': [1.1, 1.7, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 1.9],'c':[None] * 10},index=rng)


df["d"]= [0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8]
df["c"] =df.a/df.a[df.d]
```

But I just get the error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`
 
To clarify this: `df.a/df.a[0]` for the first 4 rows, `df.a/df.a[4]` for the next 4 and `df.a/df.a[8]` for the last 2 rows according to `df["d"]= [0,0,0,0,4,4,4,4,8,8]`
So how can I refer to a value in the dataframe correcty, without getting this error?

The desired output looks like this:

```
              a    b     c                       d
2011-01-01  1.1  1.1  1                          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-02  1.2  1.7  1.090909090909091          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-03  1.3  1.3  1.181818181818182          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-04  1.4  1.6  1.272727272727273          0   #  df.a/df.a[0] 
2011-01-05  1.5  1.5  1                          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-06  1.6  1.1  1.066666666666667          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-07  1.7  1.5  1.133333333333333          4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-08  1.8  1.7  1.2                        4   #  df.a/df.a[4] 
2011-01-09  1.9  2.1  1                          8   #  df.a/df.a[8] 
2011-01-10  2.0  1.9  1.052631578947368          8   #  df.a/df.a[8]
```

so it is always  `df.a/df.a[x]` for x = df.d

Comment: does `df.a[df.d]` return anything? you might want to try `df.a.loc[df.d, :]` instead.

Comment: a[df.d] rises the described error, df.a.loc[df.d, :] rises: KeyError: 'None of [2011-01-01    0\n             ..\n2011-01-10    8\nFreq: D, Name: d, dtype: int64] are in the [index]'

Comment: Can you generate some desired output (by hand)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it. Frankly I would doubt the need to have column 'd' in the data frame at all. I would keep it separate. However, if you really want to do it that way, then using your set up you can simply write:

```
df['c'] =   pd.Series([df.ix[x, 'a']/df.ix[int(df.ix[x, 'd']), 'a'] 
                       for x in xrange(len(df))],
                       index = df.index)

In [107]: df
Out[107]: 
              a    b  d         c
2011-01-01  1.1  1.1  0  1.000000
2011-01-02  1.2  1.7  0  1.090909
2011-01-03  1.3  1.3  0  1.181818
2011-01-04  1.4  1.6  0  1.272727
2011-01-05  1.5  1.5  4  1.000000
2011-01-06  1.6  1.1  4  1.066667
2011-01-07  1.7  1.5  4  1.133333
2011-01-08  1.8  1.7  4  1.200000
2011-01-09  1.9  2.1  8  1.000000
2011-01-10  2.0  1.9  8  1.052632
```

I would suggest that the following is a more sensible set up:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6, 1.7, 1.8, 1.9, 2.0], 
                    'b': [1.1, 1.7, 1.3, 1.6, 1.5, 1.1, 1.5, 1.7, 2.1, 1.9]},
                    index=rng)                  
indexer = [0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8]
df['c'] = pd.Series([df.ix[x, 'a']/df.ix[indexer[x], 'a'] for x in xrange(len(df))],
                        index = df.index)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! That works perfectly well! I think we will definitely need column d, since we need this part for a much more complex problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30682918/how-to-calculate-if-statement-for-relative-value-rebalancing-error-the-truth

Comment: This is effectively stage 2 of your other problem, with stage one being how to calculate 'd'. Is that right? If so, I am sure I can help, but I can't for the life of me understand how column d is supposed to be calculated from your other question. If you can make that clear, I'm sure I can solve it pretty easily,